# How to get the metrics that I collected using DogStatsD on dataDog?

Tags: statsd, datadog

I want to use dataDog to see how many times a java method has been called, this is my example code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X4Wm.png)

In this code, I simply want to count how many times that 'multiply' has been called, and I used DogStatsD to record the this metrics. However, when I go to the infrastructure of my dataDog, I can not find a metrics with a name similar like "multiply". What the name of the metrics should be if I set it up correctly? Can anyone help me with how can I get the metrics of the 'multiply'?
Thanks! 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziRBu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Frank,

Your use case follows the standard "custom metric" submission that is common within Datadog.  Using one of the supported libraries:

http://docs.datadoghq.com/libraries/#java

You can leverage the statsD port of an Agent running on your host to submit these custom metrics:

http://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/dogstatsd/

You will want to install the Agent on either the host running this function or point your statsD connection towards an accepting host:

http://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/basic_agent_usage/

There are additional docs found here that should help you understand how custom metrics work in Datadog:

https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204271775-What-is-a-custom-metric-and-what-is-the-limit-on-the-number-of-custom-metrics-I-can-have-

https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/203765485-How-do-I-submit-custom-metrics-What-s-their-overhead-

Usually when troubleshooting custom metric submissions, we try to implement some form of local printing/logging to ensure the statsD connection is being made and that the custom function is being called and submitted.  Once you can confirm the metric is being sent to the Agent, use the Metric Summary page to check for the custom metric:

https://app.datadoghq.com/metric/summary

If all else fails, reach out to Datadog at support@datadoghq.com